# How to find the workspace location in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I had changed the workspace path in eclipse(I do not remember the same). Recently i got my laptop re-imaged and had to install the eclipse. I am not able to get back the new workspace. i searched for the folder in the laptop. i do not find the project folder in the laptop. not sure how to get back the changed workspace.

Comment: right click on project, go to properties and see the location

Comment: I am not working on any project as of now. My Eclipse looks like new. i am not able to search for the workspace i was working earlier.

Comment: I wnat the workspace which i was working earlier. The default workspace does not work for me as i had changed the workspace earlier.

Comment: If your laptop was re-imaged, did you keep and restore a copy of your workspace? It could have been erased when the laptop was re-imaged.

Answer (score 1):

However you're launching Eclipse now, modify the procedure to add the `-showlocation` parameter. The workspace location will be embedded in the title bar.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Project > Properties > Resource > Linked Resources > Path Variables > WORKSPACE_LOC

[image: Eclipse Work space Details]

Answer (score 0):

Elipse usually stores some metadata in every workspace it works on. Go search for a `.metadata` folder in your harddisk. Its contents should look like this:

```
.plugins/
.bak_0.log
.bak_1.log
.bak_2.log
.lock
.log
version.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the project folder and have no idea, where it might be?
In this case you could try to search for *.project* files (using windows explorer) Should you find it, use *File->Switch Workspace* and select the folder two layers above the .project file. (e.g. *C:/workspace* if you found the file at *C:/Workspace/myproject/.project*)

Answer (score 0):

On my workspace, I have, besides some projects directories, two Eclipse directories:

```
.metadata
.recommenders
```

Inside `.metadata` I have:

[image]

If you're in Windows, use [this](https://superuser.com/questions/116514/how-to-search-for-only-folders-in-windows-7-instead-of-folders-and-files) tool to search for it. If you're on Linux, use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123305/how-to-find-a-folder-on-my-server-with-a-certain-name)